# How does Visual Basic's Type Inference work with Equals Operator

Tags: vb.net, type-inference

I'm working on a legacy Visual Basic (VB.NET) project and enabled Option Strict, which generates a bunch of errors due to implicit conversion.

I'm trying to eliminate these errors with minimal change to the program i.e. explicitly convert to the same type VB was implicitly converting.

One of the errors is:

> BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Double'.

The line of code is an If statement checking for equality using the Equals operator. The left operand is a Long and the right operand is a string.

Ultimately to 'fix' this example, one would explicitly convert one of the operands to the same type as the other, but which operand and which type most closely matches what VB is doing with Option Strict Off?

Based on the error it seems to be the right operand.
In general, how does VB work out which operand to do the type conversion?

Why is it attempting to convert the string to a Double instead of a Long to match the left operand? Is the left operand implicitly converted from Long to Double?

```vb
Dim l As Long = 123
Dim s As String = "123"

If l = s Then
    ' Do Something
Else
   ' Do the other thing
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `If l.ToString = s`?

Comment: @preciousbetine That will get rid of the error, but I'm trying to understand exactly what VB is doing when it implicitly converts one of these operands and explicitly convert.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the IL generated when using implicit conversion?